# How to pass Button component's title into a function in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to pass the title of a React Native Button component into a neighbouring function. I am using React Native functional components only for this application.

Here's the component. I would like to pass the title of the button pressed by the user, which will be either 'English' or 'Arabic', into the function `submitLanguageSelection` so that I can then save that value into `useLocalStorage()`, a custom hook I wrote to handle `AsyncStorage`, so that the next time the user uses the app, their language choice will be persisted, and they will not be shown the `ChooseYourLanguageScreen` again.

All help appreciated, thank you.

```
const ChooseYourLanguageScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [saveData, storedValue, errorMessage] = useLocalStorage();
  const [userSelectedLanguage, setUserSelectedLanguage] = React.useState('');

  const submitLanguageSelection = () => {
    //TODO: receive params from onPress
    //TODO: save the data locally
    //TODO: navigate to welcome screen
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {errorMessage ? <Text>{errorMessage}</Text> : null}
      <Text style={styles.text}>This is the Choose Your Language Screen</Text>
      <View style={styles.buttons}>
        <View>
          <Button
            title={'English'}
            onPress={() => submitLanguageSelection()}
          />
        </View>
        <View>
          <Button title={'Arabic'} onPress={() => submitLanguageSelection()} />
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply pass it to the function

```
 <Button title={'Arabic'} onPress={() => submitLanguageSelection('Arabic')} />
```

And access like below

```
  const submitLanguageSelection = (language) => {
    console.log(language);
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

Getting data from a sibling component is an anti-pattern.

The source of the knowledge of the language options is the `ChooseYourLanguageScreen` component (as seems from your snippet), so it should hold the list of available languages. Having that, you can just iterate through them and render the appropriate components:

```js
<View style={styles.buttons}>
  {languages.map((language) => (
    <View key={language}>
      <Button
        title={language}
        onPress={() => submitLanguageSelection(language)}
      />
    </View>
  ))}
</View>
```